# Find cell value that matches from one tab to another. If theres a match return the value in the right cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tabs in an excel work book.

Named Sheet2 and one named $.

I would like to match the cell contents in cell B2 (Sheet2) which is a product ID, in tab ($) in the range if cells A2:A1800. If there is a match i would like to return the value of the corresponding cell on tab $ next to the right of the matching cell (this is the price of the product ID)

Ideally i'd like to use a vlookup or a function

Comment: What's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: Did you try using the vlookup function?? That should do the trick.... Show us what you've tried and we'll help, but you gotta go first, mate!!!

Answer (score 0):

=VLOOKUP(B2,'$'!A2:B1800,2,FALSE)

If you want the cell to the right you have to include column B in the range.